# What is, if there is, a useful kernel function in Gaussian Process regression for bell curve-like functions with unknown mean, variance, and height?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

Let us look at a family of random functions $f_{m,\sigma^2,c}(x)=c\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, where $m\in\mathbf{R}$, $\sigma^2>0$, and $c>0$ are random parameters. Let $f_{m_0,\sigma_0^2,c_0}$ be a corresponding particular realization for fixed $m_0$, $\sigma_0^2$, and $c_0$.

Consider we want to perform Gaussian Process regression (GPR) to estimate $f_{m_0,\sigma_0^2,c_0}$.

I learned that following an ad hoc approach, i.e., choosing a stationary kernel, as e.g. the RBF kernel, is not suitable here.
[image: GPR with a stationary kernel.]
Hyperparameter optimization chooses the length scale of the stationary kernel based on the width of the bell curve.
This is "bad" in the sense that the uncertainties in regions with some distance to the mean are unreasonably high; see the figure.
Of course, this is not surprising due to the choice of a stationary kernel.

**Questions:**

1. Probably depending on the distributions of the parameters $m$, $\sigma^2$, and $c$, is $(f_{m,\sigma^2,c}(x))_{x\in\mathbf{R}}$ actually a Gaussian process?
   In other words, is there a suitable kernel function?
2. Does the GPR approach actually make sense? I like this idea since it can quantify uncertainty which could be exploited in an active learning approach, i.e., finding an optimal sequence of measure locations when a single evaluation of $f_{m_0,\sigma_0^2,c_0}$ is expensive.

Comment: Good questions for which I have no answers. Maybe a pointer or two will be useful. Reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) has a growing literature in statistics, seeing use in describing nonlinear dependence structures. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space  Another topic that may (or may not) be insightful concerns Gaussian and sub-Gaussian processes with heavy tails, e.g., median of means and trimmed mean estimators. Lugosi's work here may be a pointer https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04280   FWIW...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $(f_{m,\sigma^2,c}(x))$ is not a Gaussian process. To qualify as Gaussian process all point evaluations of your function must have a joint Gaussian distribution. This is impossible for your $f$ since it is in particular always positive.
2. GP regression seems to be an overkill anyways. You have a known parametric family of functions and - as I understand - you just want to determine the three parameters of this family for each realisation. Why can't you just observe three values of $f$ at different locations and then solve for the three parameters? Furthermore, there seems to be no uncertainty in the estimation since your function is deterministic given the random inputs.

Finally, I do not understand what is expensive about evaluating $c\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)?$

Comment: 1. Correct.
2. Also correct.

Of course, evaluating $f_{m,\sigma^2,c}$ is cheap if I know the parameters $m,\sigma,c$. But I do not know them. What I do is observing values for some $x$'s and these observations are expensive.

Comment: Most probably, it is more useful is to perform Gaussian process regression for $\log f_{m,\sigma^2,c}$.